# EILSEQ with fgetws() and UTF-8

Tags: c, utf-8, wchar

The following C code reads lines from `stdin` using `fgetws()` and writes them to `stdout`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#define STR_LEN 128

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *infile = stdin, *outfile = stdout;
    wchar_t str[STR_LEN];

    if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "en.UTF-8") == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set locale\n");
        return 1;
    }


    for (;;) {

        if (!fgetws(str, STR_LEN, infile)) {
            if (feof(infile)) {
                break;
            }
            perror("fgetws()");
            continue;
        }
        str[wcscspn(str, L"\r\n")] = L'\0';

        if (fwprintf(outfile, L"%ls\n", str) < 0) {
            perror("fwprintf()");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

It always works perfectly with ASCII files, but sometimes it gets `EILSEQ` error (Illegal byte sequence) from `fgetws()` when reading UTF-8 data, and I cannot figure out why.

In the output file, the line which causes the error is truncated, then some characters are missing and the remaining part is on the next line.
The strange thing is that if I give only that line, then I will not get any error.

For example, if I read a file with just a few UTF-8 lines, it's ok; if I repeat the same lines many times, then I get `EILSEQ`.

I'm almost sure that the file is correctly encoded.

I use Linux with musl-libc.

What's wrong in my code?

**EDIT:**
I get several `EILSEQ` errors, depending on the input size, but I don't know the exact relationship beetween the two.

With the same input I get the same errors at the same lines.

It does not seem to be a specific offset or character which triggers the error, but I might be wrong.

**EDIT 2:**
I tested the code also on OpenBSD and it works. At this point I suspect that this issue is related to Linux or musl-libc.

Comment: `str[strcspn(str, "\r\n")] = 0;` might be a better way.

Comment: Does it always fail at the same point in the file? Do you get one EILSEQ errors or two? What is the precise byte offset of the character which triggers the error and the utf-8 code for that character?

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 uses `char` to store characters, it works the same way as ANSI. The only difference is that a linguistic character can be longer than one character.

`wchar_t` and wide-c string functions are used for UTF-16 in Windows. In Linux you would use `char16_t` to store UTF-16, but only if you are working with UTF-16 files. That's clearly not the case here.

Just use `char` functions to handle UTF-8, the exact same way you work with ANSI:

```
char str[STR_LEN];
while(fgets(str, STR_LEN, infile))
{
    str[strcspn(str, "\r\n")];
    fprintf(outfile, "%s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the above program will work even with `char` strings. But if I need to manipulate single characters after reading, then I will need `wchar_t`, right? I prefer to not use external libraries (e.g. ICU), because I need to do only simple things.

Comment: Aren't you using Linux? `whcar_t` is used in Windows, it's rarely used in Linux. Just use `char`. You can parse the text if you are just searching for ANSI characters like `'\n'` or `','` because those characters don't repeat elsewhere. Treat it as regular ANSI text. But if you have something like `"ελληνικά"` then it's very difficult to find `'η'`, because `'η'` is a combination of different characters, you would rarely need that option.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to perform operations on non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Okay, then you may need external libraries. Your console input is UTF-8. You have to convert to UTF-32. Then store it in `char32_t` (or `wchar_t`). Now each character occupies 4 bytes. That's if you wanted to find the position of `'η'` in `"ελληνικά"`. Note however, it's easy to find the position of `','` in `"ελλ,ηνικά"` (it won't be at index 3, but you just go through the string and find it)